# Properly override a admin template file in Magento

Tags: magento

I want to properly override this admin template file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/form/address.phtml`

From what I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790119/551713), the proper way is to create a layout file in a new module, set template path inside my module directory and reference that template file using reference node. But I have no clue how to do that.

I don't understand how the layout is controlled using xml as of now. Can someone show how to actually do that?

Comment: You seem to have missed the xml config. It's all about the config. You'll need to create a `<rewrite>` node in your config in order to redirect from the existing template to your new one. Sign up to Magento U and get the 'Developing for Magento Basics' video series. It's got all this and more in. I'm learning from it atm!

Comment: @DavidYell Yeah! This stuff is going over my head right now. I have signed up for Magento U. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: The videos are very good, but I still recommend the experience of going to an actual course if you can afford it.

Comment: @VernBurton You mean the paid courses of Magento U?

Comment: Yes, I do.  They allow better interaction that the videos just don't provide.

Comment: `<rewrite>` is how you override PHP classes, but if you are doing a design update, you just need to include a layout update in your config.xml so that it will change what you need in your module.

Comment: @DavidYell Videos are really helping. I am in a much better shape now but can you point out the video name in which they cover overriding a admin template file? This has been stuck for long and I need to wrap it up now.

Comment: @VernBurton Thanks! But these videos seem to be just what was missing for me. I am learning, but haven't actually got to the part which answers this question.

Comment: @DavidYell Yes I am but all the info and bits of info doesn't link together how can I do it. Any code examples that I can checkout? I have learnt overriding models, blocks, helpers, resourceModels but not overriding admin template files. `setTemplate` when called inside a block will set the template path in the current theme folder and not in the module folder itself, right? *confused*

Answer (score 2):

You should really create your own module, which you can then create a new template.

If you want to force is you need `setTemplate()` which takes your phtml path as a param. `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('my_module/blockname')->setTemplate('my_module/template.phtml');`

Bear in mind that the two slash notations here are different.

`createBlock()` is for a block, so will be in `/app/code/<codePool>/My/Module/Blocks/<blockname.php>`

`setTemplate()` is for the template, so will be in `/app/design/<area>/default/default/template/template.phtml`

Your `<area>` will be /adminhtml as you're in the admin backend.

In order to get the template working you'll need to create a new module and extend the adminhtml block file which uses this template. You'll have to find the block from the layout.xml and then you can extend the Block and specify a new template.

That's how I'd go about it, but I'm also really finding it hard to override things in the Adminhtml module.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought of overriding the block itself which defines that template instead of just using xml to switch templates for that block but I feel its like using a bigger sword for a small fight :D I think I will have to use the big sword for now.

Comment: I'm finding that everything in Magento needs a "big sword" if you want to change something you have to create a whole new module just for that. I've got the problem that I've got two modules overriding the thing that I want to override! argh!

Comment: Hah, yes I am yet to run into that situation but if I recall correctly, the instructor in video says he will show in the course how we can handle that.